# How to make a .box file for Tesseract OCR in C#?

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to train a .tiff image using [this tesseract box editor](https://github.com/scotts48/tesseract-box-editor) 
but it doesn't automatically create a .box file which is a requirement to start the training. So how can I create a .box file for a specific image?
If possible, without using third party apps.

Answer (score 1):

You should try JTessBoxEditor. It's quite easy to use.

Here's the link:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/vietocr/files/jTessBoxEditor/

Also this video can be helpful for further operations:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_1-hGsXxy8